# Finding Partial Derivatives given a function that satisfies

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am given the problem

> Let $z$ be a function that depends of $x$ and $y$ and satisfies $\sin(x+y)+\sin(y+z)+\sin(x+z)=0$

And asked to find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$?

What I got was: $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\cos(x+y)}{\cos(y+z)+\cos(x+z)}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

Is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: My partial wrt x is coming as $$\frac{-cos(x+y) - cos(x+z)}{cos(y+z)+cos(x+z)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$F=\sin(x+y)+\sin(y+z)+\sin(x+z)=0$$ and computing the partial derivatives $$F'_x=\cos (x+y)+\cos (x+z)$$ $$F'_y=\cos (x+y)+\cos (y+z)$$ $$F'_z=\cos (x+z)+\cos (y+z)$$ and by the implicit function theorem $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_z}=-\frac{\cos (x+y)+\cos (x+z)}{\cos (x+z)+\cos (y+z)}$$ $$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-\frac{F'_y}{F'_z}=-\frac{\cos (x+y)+\cos (y+z)}{\cos (x+z)+\cos (y+z)}$$